# Как c помощью аналитических функций получить предыдущее значение прошлой группы в текущей группе?

Tags: sql

Предположим есть данные:

```
create table ttt (id integer, grp varchar(10),amount decimal(16,2))  
insert into ttt values (1,'GRP1',500)  
insert into ttt values (1,'GRP1',500)  
insert into ttt values (2,'GRP1',400)  
insert into ttt values (2,'GRP1',400)  
insert into ttt values (2,'GRP1',400);
```

Необходимо получить на выходе такую таблицу:

```
id grp  amount prev_amount  
1  GRP1 500    null  
1  GRP1 500    null  
2  GRP1 400    500  
2  GRP1 400    500  
2  GRP1 400    500
```

Обычный LAG or LEAD не подходят, потому что они делают смещение под одинаковый набор данных(последняя строка с GRP1 400 будем иметь прошлое значение null, так как неоткуда было переносить прошлое значение), а тут как мы видим в ID = 1 2 строки, а в ID = 2 уже 3 строки, и их может быть какое угодно кол-во, хоть 1 строка или более 3ех.

Придумал весьма кастыльное решение, через 2 подзапроса.

```
select  
t.*, max(prev_grp_amount) over (partition by id,grp) as final_prev_amount   
from ( 
select 
    t.id
    ,t.grp
    ,t.amount
    ,lag(AMOUNT,cnt) over (partition by GRP order by id asc) as prev_grp_amount
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by GRP,id) as cnt from ttt as t) as t
) as t
order by id;
```

Для начала я формирую динамический отступ для функции LAG (cnt), затем получаю почти корректный перенос AMOUNT на следущую группу, но ввиду того что полного соответствия для каждой строки не имею, то получаю NULL в одной строчке. Чтобы убрать этот NULL приходится еще в одном подзапросе использовать еще одну аналитическую функцию MAX() по разрезу.
Считаю этот вариант слишком кастыльным и неправильным. Кто может придумать более корректное решение?

Comment: А если бы в первых двух строках (с id=1) были разные значения amount, то какое из них должно было бы попасть в следующую группу ?

Comment: в данном случае AMOUNT в рамках всех группы текущего id будет всегда одинаковый. Я просто для примера немного упростил разрез данных, в конечном разрезе присутствует еще один столбец, который дробить каждую GRP на ряд других данных. Но это не мешает основной задаче, поэтому я ее немного упростил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.*, max(p_amount) over(partition by id)
  from (
    select ttt.*,
           case when id != lag(id) over(order by id) then lag(amount) over(order by id) end p_amount
      from ttt
  ) x
```

Comment: Похоже на мою предложенную реализацию, но меня не покидает чувство, что это как-то решается грамотнее. Возможно как-то поиграться с RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING...

Comment: @Alexxx Крайне мало вероятно что это решается с помощью range. Тем более вы в вопросе не указали диалекта SQL, а в разных СУБД у range очень сильно отличающиеся возможности. Боюсь тут уже нужен хирургический скальпель, который например в oracle дает model